# Maven do not show any logs in Jenkins

Tags: java, maven, jenkins

I am working with ***Jenkins*** (jenkins-1.571), also I used **Apache maven 3.0.5** . My maven setting is here

[image]

and maven configuration of my job is here (it is fragment whole job)

[image]

but when I build this job **Jenkins** does not show any maven logs, just logs `Completed with SUCCESS/ERROR`

[image]

Finally I want to view maven logs like console

Comment: are you sure you are kicking off the same job ?

Comment: can you post job's xml file it would be there in somewhere in `JENKINS_DIR/jobs/job_name/`

Comment: You are working not that job, cause in the line `Triggering default` you can see that the job `default` is triggered. There you should take a look into.

Comment: " khmarbaise" Thank you man. please write this comment as answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are working not that job, cause in the line Triggering default you can see that the job default is triggered. There you should take a look into.